# Is there a way to deal with this singularity in numerical integration of a bessel function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-calculus

I would like to numerically integrate the following function:

$I = \int^{a}_{-a}\int^{b}_{-b}Y_0(r)dx dy$

Where: $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and $Y_0$ is a 0 order bessel function of the second kind.

But there is a singularity at r=0 so the calculation dosn't converge. Is there a way to deal with this sort of problem?

Comment: You might consider each quadrant separately, using a product form of quadrature catering to the logarithmic singularity at the origin. There are several, [here's one](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1993-60-201/S0025-5718-1993-1155572-3/).

Comment: Thanks this fixed the issue